# NASM Modulo operation

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, modulo

I just started assembling with the NASM Assembler. Compiling with gcc using a C-driver. As much as I know, one can implement a **modulo function** in two ways easily (assuming `size_t a` in `eax`, `size_t b` in `ebx` for `mod(a, b)`):

first option:

```
minus:
  sub eax, ebx
modulo:
  CMP eax, ebx
  JGE minus
  leave   ; else result is already saved in eax
  ret
```

second option:

```
 modulo:         ; calcs eax mod ebx, returns eax
    mov edx, 0  ; clear higher 32-bits as edx:eax / ebx is calced
    div ebx     
    mov eax, edx ; the remainder was stored in edx
    leave      
    ret
```

The following are the required files:

diver.c:

```
#include "cdecl.h"
#include "stdio.h"

int PRE_CDECL asm_main( size_t, size_t ) POST_CDECL;

int main() {
    size_t a;
    size_t b;
    int result;
    a = 15;
    b = 5;
    result = asm_main(a, b);
    printf("%d", result);
    return 0;
}
```

modulo.asm:

```
segment .data
buffer: times 1 dd 0    ; define a 32-bit buffer

segment.text
global asm_main

modulo:
  ; one of above options implemented here

asm_main:
    enter 0, 0
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp    ; save the stack pointer on ebp
    pusha

    ; dump_regs 0 ,requires %include "asm_io.inc"
    mov eax, [ebp + 12]    ; move first argument to eax
    mov ebx, [ebp + 16]    ; move second argument to ebx
    ; dump_regs 1

    call modulo                ; result is saved in eax now
    ; dump_regs 2

    mov ecx, buffer        ; get buffer's address into the register
    mov [ecx], eax           ; save the modulo result into the buffer

    popa
    pop ebp

    mov eax, [buffer]        ; move the saved result back into eax
    leave
    ret
```

Compilation works fine:

```
$ nasm -f elf modulo.asm
$ gcc -m32 -c driver.c
$ gcc -m32 -o modulo driver.o modulo.o
```

When executing using both options, a Segmentation Fault is received somehow:

```
$ ./modulo
Register Dump # 0
EAX = 00000001 EBX = F76D0000 ECX = FFF987F0 EDX = FFF98814
ESI = 00000000 EDI = 00000000 EBP = FFF987A4 ESP = FFF98784
EIP = 080484EE FLAGS = 0296       SF    AF PF   
Register Dump # 1
EAX = 0000000F EBX = 00000005 ECX = FFF987F0 EDX = FFF98814
ESI = 00000000 EDI = 00000000 EBP = FFF987A4 ESP = FFF98784
EIP = 080484FB FLAGS = 0296       SF    AF PF   
Segmentation fault
```

I don't know where I might try to access an address outside of the environment, so I couldn't figure out yet where the error is.

I'd appreciate it if someone could help me finding the troublemaker or suggest me a working modulo function in Assembler (intel syntax preferred, if possible). Thanks!

PS: The `asm_io.asm`, `asm_io.inc` and `cdecl.h` can be found in [this link](https://srv2.mysnet.me/casm/resources).

Comment: What's up with that unbalanced `leave` ? Is there some secret code above it that does the function prolog?

Comment: Why do you have both an `enter` instruction and a `push ebp ; mov ebp, esp` sequence in `asm_main`? Effectively, you setup the stack frame twice which might be what causes your error.

Comment: Similarly, as @harold says, you try to `leave` a stack frame in `minus` and `modulo` that you haven't set up before.  What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Thanks guys, using the option with the `div` instruction without `leave` was the solution. I naively thought I'd have to `leave` before `ret` in general, so this helped me understanding things a little more :) First option (with substraction) delivers BS numbers now, each run differently, though. Do you maybe know why? PS: I think your comments were worth an answer, so I added it.

Comment: @christopherwestburry There is nothing you have to do “in general.” Every instruction has a defined effect.  Only issue an instruction when you want its effect to be performed.  Don't write code you do not understand.  If you don't know what `enter` and `leave` do, do not use them!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @fuz , @harold for the comments. I guess your comments can become an answer, actually :)

Changing the second option to

```
modulo:         ; calcs eax mod ebx, returns eax
    mov edx, 0  ; clear higher 32-bits as edx:eax / ebx is calced
    div ebx     
    mov eax, edx ; the remainder was stored in edx     
    ret
```

solves the entire problem.

Caution: The first option returns a wrong value even if `leave` removed.

---

Addendum:

As Peter Cordes stated, using `asm_main` is actually not a good practice. So I have modified both options in the C convention as following:

first option:

```
modulo:    ; Function size_t modulo(a, b)
        mov     eax, dword [esp+4H]    ; a in EAX
        mov     edx, dword [esp+8H]    ; b in EDX
        cmp     eax, edx               ; if (a < b) -> return
        JL      return

minus:  sub     eax, edx               ; else: a = a-b
        cmp     eax, edx               ; if (a >= b) -> minus
        JGE     minus
return:                                ; else: return
        ret
```

second option:

```
modulo:
        mov     eax, dword [esp+4H]   ; a in EAX
        mov     edx, 0                ; EDX should be zero
        div     dword [esp+8H]        ; a / b
        mov     eax, edx              ; move a % b to eax
        ret
```

*modulo.asm*:

```
global modulo

segment .text

modulo:    ; insert one of the options above here
```

*modulodriver.c*:

```
#include "cdecl.h"
#include "stdio.h"

unsigned int PRE_CDECL modulo( unsigned int, unsigned int ) POST_CDECL;

int main() {
    unsigned int a = 25;
    unsigned int b = 5;
    unsigned int result = modulo(a, b);
    printf("%d", result);
    return 0;
}
```

I have tested both options and the work just fine :)

Note: If compiling with the `-m32` option, one can use `size_t` instead of `unsigned int`, but `size_t` will be a 64-bit integer, those larger than the used registers on 64-bit systems, though.

Comment: Taking args in EBX is non-standard; that register is normally call-preserved.  If you're using the `gcc -m32 -mregparm=2` calling convention, your args are in EAX and ECX.  (Then you don't need a wacky `asm_main` that's nearly as complicated as the compiler-generated `main`!)  Anyway, you should use `xor edx,ebx` / `div ecx` / `mov eax, edx` / `ret` to get a function you can call from C as `__attribute__((regparm(2))) unsigned modulo(unsigned a, unsigned b);`.  That's also what `gcc -O3` would emit if you wrote it in C and looked at a stand-alone non-inline version.

Comment: Your function is looking for its args on the stack, rather than `edi` and `esi`, so 64-bit code can't call it anyway.  The calling convention is different.  Compare `-m32` vs. 64-bit compiler code-gen: https://godbolt.org/g/TRVHCK for `unsigned modulo(unsigned a, unsigned b) {
    return a%b;
}`